# Remove “whitespace” between 2 div element under one another

Tags: html, css

```css
.div-1 {
  background-color: #deb887;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div-2 {
  background-color: #87ceeb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 32px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">..... some code here </div>
<div class="div-2">..... some code here</div>
```

a white space is coming between 2 div, under one another
I found some solution of this problem, but they are not working.

1. vertical-align: top; ----- not working
2. line-height: 0px; ------ it effects on the text of div
3. font-size: 0px; ------- it also effects on text

   4. *{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      ------------------ not working

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the white line in your example?!

Comment: Since the elements are 100% wide there is no reason to use `inline-block` at all.

Comment: working when display:block with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.div-1{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #deb887;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
}

.div-2 {
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #87ceeb;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 32px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @N. Josh i am not sure but you can check it by applying it in css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<div class="div-1">..... some code here </div><!--
--><div class="div-2">..... some code here</div>
```

Please note the comment syntax